# Populating excel sheet with data from word documents

Tags: excel

I have the following problem:

On one side I have around 200 forms in Excel, all of them are in the same format. First page is a disclaimer and I do not need, second one contains a table which I need to extract.

The table has 2 columns: first one says what the info is (name, address etc) second one has the information. What I need to do is to take the data from the second column of each individual form and populate them in Excel.

So far I have tried to:

- Combine all the forms into a single word, convert the word doc into a txt file, import to excel. Because there is data in the first page and various things before and after the table, everything comes out very messy. One case without using delimiters, all the data is in just one column. If I use delimiters it goes in like 7-8 columns, not same things in a column.

Any suggestions?

PS some of the cells in Word might have different amount. For example column A has "address", but there might be between 2-4 lines of address in column B.

Comment: Each Word table can be directly addressed from Excel. Do a search on using VBA to loop through all Word documents in a folder. Then search on how to loop through tables in a word document. You'll be able to identify each table by the content. Finally you can then loop through each row of the table.

Comment: Thanks, I do however have very limited knowledge of VBA. Could you please guide me a bit more?